# Creating content type in Orchard

Tags: orchardcms, content-type, orchardcms-1.10

I need to create a specific type of content from the fields tied to specific locations template. so i can create an instance of that content with already pre-arranged fields on a template. when i create an instance of content, all fields have to stand in their places. For example, logo on the left, top right name, right below the description.
P.s. sorry for my english

Comment: Here you can find many tutorials: https://orcharddojo.net/?__r=1271502825 about orchard and also there is a video tutorial on youtube on this channel: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLuskKJW0FhJdI_I3bhEBYw5BZBiWmsjtK

Comment: This sounds like the most basic form of starting with Orchard. Please read up about some documentation and/or tutorials